# can anyone decode this javascript please

Tags: javascript, decode

i have tried all decoder but no result for this javascript code, and i dont know what encode type for this javascript code, anyone can help me or just type of this encode.
i have tried online javascript decode, uri decode and base64 decode no result for this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
<!--
var x="function f(x){var i,o=\"\",ol=x.length,l=ol;while(x.charCodeAt(l/13)!" +
"=48){try{x+=x;l+=l;}catch(e){}}for(i=l-1;i>=0;i--){o+=x.charAt(i);}return o" +
".substr(0,ol);}f(\")24,\\\"020\\\\230\\\\220\\\\100\\\\500\\\\030\\\\HVLD61" +
"0\\\\430\\\\qBo@%771\\\\uzvb:(-ku771\\\\mz\\\"\\\\0eV{T9tq+?\\\"\\\\! ^]\\\\"+
"\\\\[Z720\\\\$500\\\\*K020\\\\700\\\\]MNM29%&(<;E:X100\\\\620\\\\610\\\\000" +
"\\\\620\\\\771\\\\|100\\\\(27;-$tt\\\\i6\\\"\\\\($ol120\\\\8\\\"\\\\'+=4d13" +
"0\\\\y&/ .730\\\\430\\\\a700\\\\^TVV720\\\\410\\\\[[ZFPB@MHH600\\\\^QMS600\\"+
"\\630\\\\\\\\\\\\S420\\\\100\\\\Xo.=&|tp|swe4(ja >.7xcm`z*hlcqcl E500\\\\41" +
"0\\\\OHYB300\\\\630\\\\220\\\\530\\\\620\\\\230\\\\\\\\\\\\520\\\\100\\\\70" +
"0\\\\100\\\\LP220\\\\130\\\\\\\\\\\\UF_020\\\\310\\\\500\\\\010\\\\500\\\\7" +
"~f$+hhxm3/= 771\\\\%> (mw )&$%k **./)730\\\\400\\\\D]WJJQS620\\\\610\\\\QG[" +
"YG710\\\\420\\\\_CGEJ010\\\\430\\\\420\\\\720\\\\A520\\\\@220\\\\300\\\\?zt" +
"pti9`g'5.awub`l-7;?=IF0&$9fou120\\\\710\\\\330\\\\020\\\\130\\\\030\\\\230\\"+
"\\U*H120\\\\730\\\\310\\\\500\\\\300\\\\O230\\\\030\\\\430\\\\500\\\\300\\\\"+
"U600\\\\;420\\\\9Z120\\\\000\\\\]^;*a|{zyxwvuts<r\\\\\\\"\\\\320\\\\p)8dvw&" +
"&66k771\\\\| o300\\\\sr771\\\\520\\\\}w}xr{uqapd120\\\\410\\\\qGEKEJx400\\\\"+
"y130\\\\WGFR~j=>G5twt8rzv}u~nl~m771\\\\$~771\\\\p)*>svuh\\\\\\\\!A530\\\\73" +
"0\\\\310\\\\020\\\\W720\\\\IJ\\\\\\\\000\\\\320\\\\L330\\\\600\\\\n\\\\500\\"+
"\\130\\\\320\\\\130\\\\700\\\\$XG8X610\\\\r\\\\100\\\\2-p${`<\\\"\\\\>%x ==" +
"7r320\\\\s( 2>:h)'57771\\\\,530\\\\2c000\\\\O^700\\\\400\\\\]L310\\\\620\\\\"+
"520\\\\420\\\\320\\\\220\\\\120\\\\020\\\\710\\\\610\\\\r\\\\BwXu620\\\\UR1" +
"30\\\\J771\\\\P}630\\\\mj2 ;:987654}NcL1jy#74+Ts~`p!^<e610\\\\400\\\\010\\\\"+
"[X%CA@CBEDRPU430\\\\200\\\\000\\\\400\\\\t\\\\ISUT000\\\\R100\\\\QB@;713(z!" +
"(fvo&66#?-l120\\\\q.&0<4fg030\\\\spc430\\\\200\\\\[GUH230\\\\330\\\\d700\\\\"+
"600\\\\500\\\\500\\\\120\\\\n410\\\\UZBLZ310\\\\010\\\\u\\\\\\\\OALAT000\\\\"+
"}530\\\\zs|r;nlhy771\\\\)zO`M.}l12o~5('&%$#\\\"\\\\! ^320\\\\ t\\\\&G430\\\\"+
"300\\\\YI]630\\\\320\\\\300\\\\720\\\\GN9$,#,?t\\\\:720\\\\8]020\\\\300\\\\" +
"\\\\\\\\a:)`{zyxwvutsr?410\\\\=220\\\\s>?v'420\\\\5230\\\\{67m}`730\\\\630\\"+
"\\530\\\\430\\\\330\\\\230\\\\130\\\\VkDin\\\\WF630\\\\410\\\\120\\\\410\\\\"+
"qXSO]n\\\\{330\\\\@TZV100\\\\200\\\\C%+*-,/.46/f|~~s/5?>n<k;$&amomr 600\\\\" +
"r\\\\M[@310\\\\530\\\\320\\\\400\\\\230\\\\620\\\\Q.L520\\\\300\\\\720\\\\1" +
"30\\\\730\\\\KH5XUD9Y600\\\\030\\\\010\\\\320\\\\771\\\\|100\\\\~700\\\\g<-" +
";7#tq610\\\\$:::220\\\\$*8,)#d130\\\\y&/ .730\\\\JHLUS500\\\\VkDin\\\\APr\\" +
"\\610\\\\KZ120\\\\410\\\\310\\\\n\\\\t\\\\010\\\\700\\\\600\\\\500\\\\400\\" +
"\\300\\\\L}RC yh4&VLyJgH-`s,1jy0+*)('&%$#\\\"\\\\o\\\\\\\\410\\\\!Bt\\\\610" +
"\\\\E620\\\\+400\\\\)J100\\\\600\\\\^LONMLKJIHt\\\\:720\\\\8]600\\\\520\\\\" +
"Oc`771\\\\000\\\\/\\\"\\\\<,un\\\\h1#+%pm220\\\\vz}|771\\\\~qee~1--/\\\\\\\\"+
"630\\\\600\\\\610\\\\t\\\\_710\\\\Z400\\\\520\\\\520\\\\PZ^^C710\\\\V]530\\" +
"\\310\\\\020\\\\[MCTJF100\\\\~430\\\\Esgio;8E(%4I)vhxc/,Q.W7l}kgs$!^mar\\\\" +
"430\\\\#320\\\\330\\\\310\\\\530\\\\620\\\\220\\\\W(N720\\\\430\\\\120\\\\1" +
"00\\\\N130\\\\130\\\\330\\\\400\\\\000\\\\TGF120\\\\8720\\\\>710\\\\<-200\\" +
"\\c.9fg<#jutsrqponml%620\\\\;420\\\\y\\\"\\\\1k771\\\\710\\\\610\\\\220\\\\" +
"yPaNg400\\\\KZ310\\\\010\\\\Q@710\\\\220\\\\120\\\\020\\\\710\\\\610\\\\r\\" +
"\\410\\\\310\\\\n\\\\t\\\\F{Ty230\\\\QV530\\\\NClArGhE&5Jpzy0M-j{am}*+Tbv|p" +
"\\\\\\\\pdi410\\\\010\\\\320\\\\030\\\\X%E220\\\\330\\\\420\\\\230\\\\SP-63" +
"0\\\\n\\\\n\\\\t\\\\500\\\\300\\\\H5U200\\\\620\\\\430\\\\020\\\\C620\\\\42" +
"0\\\\020\\\\17a(700\\\\.500\\\\6310\\\\$t\\\\ 710\\\\&r\\\\>320\\\\<120\\\\" +
"r9>ftgfedcba`QbO`500\\\\^M720\\\\310\\\\010\\\\720\\\\h300\\\\100\\\\320\\\\"+
"l220\\\\ZEKBOA010\\\\500\\\\z520\\\\120\\\\100\\\\~430\\\\Hkztk;8Ewt771\\\\" +
";z|qxfnh\\\"\\\\771\\\\nmhen)am-mb.330\\\\320\\\\620\\\\TUC010\\\\300\\\\20" +
"0\\\\530\\\\V/O220\\\\200\\\\430\\\\Nn\\\\100\\\\200\\\\V700\\\\4520\\\\:[6" +
"20\\\\100\\\\^_400\\\\+b}|{zyxwvut=610\\\\#410\\\\q&9cw030\\\\000\\\\230\\\\"+
"220\\\\r\\\\e200\\\\500\\\\310\\\\320\\\\100\\\\k630\\\\vyxTeJk010\\\\GV710" +
"\\\\410\\\\320\\\\lJBIHBG310\\\\t230\\\\HBMOCW000\\\\=Biz~v;D*xr}771\\\\s1x" +
"{2-,+*)('&%$m^s\\\\\\\\@710\\\\010\\\\G420\\\\%n\\\\+H410\\\\020\\\\430\\\\" +
"020\\\\500\\\\LONMLKJIHYD9_710\\\\300\\\\010\\\\220\\\\630\\\\~%,oky46;';53" +
"0\\\\rk$!!+n720\\\\w,$>26da630\\\\qbc300\\\\OY_HVZ720\\\\SYVRFr\\\\^s\\\\\\" +
"\\q220\\\\t\\\\vBFFJG{100\\\\~430\\\\Tzyo}o:;D/;s`f0M-{k~~jbj%sv`g`c!\\\"\\" +
"\\\\\"\\\\t\\\\710\\\\420\\\\n\\\\[$J220\\\\230\\\\430\\\\700\\\\720\\\\430" +
"\\\\PM2130\\\\730\\\\400\\\\t\\\\6410\\\\t\\\\710\\\\300\\\\K600\\\\610\\\\" +
"010\\\\200\\\\03r3=40v%?>3==~771\\\\u>98#h520\\\\u)),0 #a-MQ[000\\\\130\\\\" +
"220\\\\WTRB\\\\\\\\FD430\\\\E^JCXODN\\\"(f};o nruter};))++y(^)i(tAedoCrahc." +
"x(edoCrahCmorf.gnirtS=+o;721=%y{)++i;l<i;0=i(rof;htgnel.x=l,\\\"\\\"=o,i ra" +
"v{)y,x(f noitcnuf\")"                                                        ;
while(x=eval(x));
//-->
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Where did you find that? What does it do?

Comment: This code is obfuscated, you should search for an de-obfuscator.

Comment: Or you could just execute it (part for part) - it decodes itself. Try it!

Answer (score 3):

Just enter the code in a console and do each `eval` step manually until the variable looks like proper JavaScript. The result is then as follows.

Basically it is just (multiple times) escaped JavaScript with some Unicode encoded symbols in it. Nothing spectacular and we've had much tougher encodings here ,-)

**And as usual the warning: If this code is not added by you, your webserver has been hacked and you should take measures to clean it up and prevent it in the future.**

```
document.writeln("<form action=\"http://ongkir.info/mobile/find_cost\" method=\"post\" accept-charset=\"utf-8\" target=\"_blank\">\r\n<table border=\"0\" style=\"font: Normal 14px Arial;\">        <tbody>\r\n<tr>\r\n          <th align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\"><br>\r\nCEK TARIFF KURIR</th>\r\n          <td><br>\r\n<img src=\"http://jne.co.id/images/favicon.ico\" width=\"50\" height=\"30\"></td>\r\n        </tr>\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"courier_type\" value=\"jne\">\r\n\r\n<tr>\r\n          <td><br>\r\nFROM</td>\r\n          <td><br>\r\n\t\t  <input name=\"daerah_asal\" value=\"\" size=\"20\" style=\"border: 1px solid #3b6e22; color: #666666;\" type=\"text\"></td>\r\n        </tr>\r\n<tr>\r\n          <td><br>\r\nTO</td>\r\n          <td><br>\r\n<input name=\"daerah_tuju\" value=\"\" size=\"20\" style=\"border: 1px solid #3b6e22; color: #666666;\" type=\"text\"></td>\r\n        </tr>\r\n<tr>\r\n          <td><br>\r\nWEIGHT (gram)</td>\r\n          <td><br>\r\n<input name=\"weight\" value=\"1000\" size=\"20\" style=\"border: 1px solid #3b6e22; color: #666666;\" type=\"text\"></td>\r\n        </tr>\r\n<tr>\r\n          <td><br>\r\n<span style=\"font-size: x-small;\">Copyright<br/><a href=\"http://www.tasbandoeng.com/\" target=\"_blank\">TASBANDOENG.COM</a></span></td>\r\n          <td><br>\r\n<input style=\"background: #6AA450; border: 1px solid #3b6e22; color: white; display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; height: 24px; line-height: 24px; margin-right: 10px; padding: 0px 6px; text-decoration: none;\" name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"SUBMIT\"></td>\r\n        </tr>\r\n</tbody></table>\r\n</form>");0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't let the `eval` run in a loop, but do it manually. For the first time, you still get an escaped code, after the second run you get a `document.writeln` that outputs the following document:

```
<form action="http://ongkir.info/mobile/find_cost" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" target="_blank">
<table border="0" style="font: Normal 14px Arial;">        <tbody>
<tr>
          <th align="left" valign="middle"><br>
CEK TARIFF KURIR</th>
          <td><br>
<img src="http://jne.co.id/images/favicon.ico" width="50" height="30"></td>
        </tr>

        <input type="hidden" name="courier_type" value="jne">

<tr>
          <td><br>
FROM</td>
          <td><br>
          <input name="daerah_asal" value="" size="20" style="border: 1px solid #3b6e22; color: #666666;" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
<tr>
          <td><br>
TO</td>
          <td><br>
<input name="daerah_tuju" value="" size="20" style="border: 1px solid #3b6e22; color: #666666;" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
<tr>
          <td><br>
WEIGHT (gram)</td>
          <td><br>
<input name="weight" value="1000" size="20" style="border: 1px solid #3b6e22; color: #666666;" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
<tr>
          <td><br>
<span style="font-size: x-small;">Copyright<br/><a href="http://www.tasbandoeng.com/" target="_blank">TASBANDOENG.COM</a></span></td>
          <td><br>
<input style="background: #6AA450; border: 1px solid #3b6e22; color: white; display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; height: 24px; line-height: 24px; margin-right: 10px; padding: 0px 6px; text-decoration: none;" name="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT"></td>
        </tr>
</tbody></table>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks, you have full decoded